# How to UPSERT a record in SAP ASE Sybase 16?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, sap-iq

I am literaly following the SAP documentation 1st example on UPSERT a record in ASE:
https://help.sap.com/viewer/cbed2190ee2d4486b0bbe0e75bf4b636/16.0.3.2/en-US/faf583d9adc547ad8a164bb3f41ea6cd.html

```
1> select @@version
2> go
Adaptive Server Enterprise/16.0 SP03 PL06/EBF 28334 SMP/P/x86_64/SLES 11.1/ase1
60sp03pl06x/3457/64-bit/FBO/Mon Nov 26 04:33:30 2018
(1 row affected)

1> select * from t1
2> go
 a           b           c
 ----------- ----------- -----------
           1           2           3
(1 row affected)

1> upsert t1(a,b,c) values(1,2,3)
2> go
Msg 102, Level 15, State 181:
Server 'NPL', Line 1:
Incorrect syntax near 'a'.
```

Does anyone know why am I getting this "Incorrect syntax" error in the UPSERT statment?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the sole intent is to implement `upsert` capability in `ASE` then what you want to look at is the [merge command](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ASE/e0d4539d39c34f52ae9ef822c2060077/ab389f37bc2b10149bb5c3bafec694a1.html?locale=en-US).

If the intent is to utilize (a subset of) HANA's `SQLScript` (in this case the `upsert` command) for some sort of interoperability requirement, and keeping in mind you may need to modify existing code to work with dual (and incompatible) parsers, then ...

---

To use (a limited version of) HANA's `SQLScript` in ASE you first need to create a database that supports the `SQLScript` parser (see [Creating a SQLScript database](https://help.sap.com/viewer/cbed2190ee2d4486b0bbe0e75bf4b636/16.0.3.2/en-US/bc08c73eb102444bb64b96ee0d4e9b49.html)), eg:

```
use master
go
create database sqlscript_db
    on data_01=10
log on log_01=5
for sqlscript                  -- enable use of SQLScript parser
go
```

Running `sp_helpdb` (from a non-SQLScript db) to verify db status:

```
use master
go
sp_helpdb sqlscript_db
go

 name         db_size       owner dbid created      durability lobcomplvl inrowlen status
 ------------ ------------- ----- ---- ------------ ---------- ---------- -------- ---------
 sqlscript_db       15.0 MB sa       7 Mar 25, 2022 full                0     NULL sqlscript
... snip ...                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^
```

You should now be able to use the `upsert` statement in this new database:

```
use sqlscript_db
go
create table t1 (a int, b int, c int)
go
upsert t1(a,b,c) values(1,2,3)
go
(1 row affected)

select * from t1
go

 a           b           c
 ----------- ----------- -----------
           1           2           3
```

**NOTE:** verified on `ASE 16.0 SP04 GA`

---

Verifying `SQLScript/upsert` does not work in a non-SQLScript database:

```
use tempdb
go
create table t1 (a int, b int, c int)
go
upsert t1(a,b,c) values(1,1,1)
go

Msg 102, Level 15, State 181:
Server 'ASE400', Line 1:
Incorrect syntax near 'a'.
```

Answer (score 1):

if your unique key, let's say, is t1.a, then you can use the logic below:

```
merge into t1 as dest
using (select 1 a, 2 b, 3 c) as src
on dest.a = src.a
when not matched then
  insert (a,b,c) values(src.a,src.b,src.c)
when matched then
  update set b=src.b, c=src.c
```